# How to clear the command line if a server is running?

Tags: command-line, console

I'm used to running servers from Eclipse but since I'm switching my IDE to lightweight editor I have to run servers from command line. In Eclipse you have this nice feature on it's console to clear the screen while the server is running.

I wanted to do the same in command line. Obviously "cls" isn't going to run if I'm running my server so just wondering if there is a way or any other tool that gets this job done.

Comment: have you tried `clear`?

Comment: I'm in Windows, not Unix system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very elegant, but what I usually do is to set the Window buffer size to 1 and then back to the original value.

That's right-click on title bar / Properties / Layout.  You could also need to restore Window height to the original value.

Comment: Hey, that's better than nothing. Thanks!!